# Getting scores from Google Play Games Services, server side

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to load from a web server some scores from GPGS, using the Google API PHP Client.

Here's how I proceed:

**1/ SETTING UP THE OAUTH CLIENT**

I created the OAuth client on the Google API Console using a service account, according this doc: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

It provided me a certificate + an email address + a client_id.

**2/ WRITING PHP CODE**

Here's my code:

```
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setApplicationName("");
 $client->setAssertionCredentials(
      new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
           "something@developer.gserviceaccount.com", // email provided by console
           array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games'), // scope
           file_get_contents("../certificates/certificate.p12")  // keyfile i downloaded
      )
 );
 $service = new Google_Service_Games($client);
 $service->scores->listScores("myLeaderboardId", "PUBLIC", "ALL_TIME");
```

**3/ FIRST RESULTS**

The first weird thing about this snippet, is that the API thrown me an error with an HTTP status 401 with this message:

> Request was missing required scope(s): *plus.login*

According the official documentation (https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores/list) the required scope for this request is only *games*

**4/ HITTING A WALL**

Adding this scope to my request was really not a big deal, but after that, the API responded me again with a 401 HTTP status:

> User has not completed registration

which I completly understand, since I am using credentials from a service account, and not a real account.

**QUESTION**

What am I doing wrong? Do I really can load leaderboards by calling the Google API from a server?

Thanks in advance for helping me,

Regards,